# How to add coordinating nodes for Elasticsearch service on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

We need to add a coordinating node on `AWS Elasticsearch` but having trouble figuring out how. Is it possible at all? How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, AWS Elasticsearch does not support "coordinating only" nodes as of now.

By default, every data node that you add in the cluster acts as a coordinating node. All the incoming requests are first received by the load balancer and then served by one of the "acting" coordinating node (changes for every request). This  coordinating node is selected from the available data nodes in a [round robin](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/category/amazon-elasticsearch-service/) fashion so that the load distributed equally amount the configured number of data nodes.